# including file in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

directory structure in my ci setup is

```
application
system
    public_html
```

my home controller render view (/home/index) now I want inside index view to render _mainMenu.php which is saved outside home so I tried at /home/index view  `<?php include '../_mainMenu.php' ?>`

but this error occures

> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Warning
>
> Message: include(): Failed opening '../_mainMenu.php' for inclusion
>   (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php')
>
> Filename: home/index.php

If I put mainMenu.php inside /home directory and call `<?php include '_mainMenu.php' ?>` everything works, but I want this file to be accessible to all pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't include views in codeigniter you load them via:

```
$this->load->view('name');
```

You should read up on the [**docs**](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/general/views.html) if you're going to use it.

Answer (score 1):

If the file is a view file and you want to access it on all pages, then you can just create a view file and then loaded them in your view using the below syntax.

```
$this->view('your_file');
```

Please note that in CI, we have the view object available in all views, so we dont use the load object as we use in controllers.

Also please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9402924/how-to-load-view-into-another-view-codeigniter-2-1) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15096828/load-a-view-inside-another-view)

But if your file is not a view file and has some other common code which should run on all pages, then it will be great to create a parent controller and place all that code in constructor of that parent controller.

For example, you want to get the menu items from database, also check the clicked menu item and etc etc, then it will be great to do it in a parent controller and extend all your controllers from that parent controller. Check the below skeleton code:

```
class FrontController extends CI_Controller {

  public function __contstruct()
   {
        parent::__construct();  //Please note to call the CI_Controller constructor as always. 

      //place all your common code here
   }

} //End of FrontController
```

Now lets consider another controller like HomeController:

```
class HomeController extends FrontController {


   public function index() {

       //the index function
     }
 }
```

Now i home controller you can see clearly that HomeController is extended from FrontController. Now all common code placed in the FrontController constructor will be available in all controllers extended from FrontController.

I hope this will help.

Thank you